# Replacing sync function with async in node js without using await

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, controller

New to node/Typescript

Trying to change few things in common library/service but not working exactly as expected -->

```
export function header(requestData: any): any {
  
  const headers: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  const config = { headers };
  config.headers = headers;
  if (requestData !== undefined) {
    if (requestData.headers.authorization !== undefined) {
     //before code changes :-  config.headers.authorization = buildToken(id);
   ** config.headers.authorization = asyncFunctionGetToken();**
    }
  }
  return config;
}
```

Dont want to use await as it will change to async function and it has refer to almost thousand places. Any suggestion?

Thanks in adavnce.

await and async combination tried but then have to change reference to almost 100 + files.
asyncFunc.then but its returning auth header as promise which i dont want.

Comment: If `asyncFunctionGetToken()` returns a `Promise` then your options are (1) `await` its result or (2) follow the `Promise` with a `.then()` callback and access its result therein.  We can appreciate that you *want* it to just return its result synchronously, and you're certainly not the first person to want that, but that simply isn't how it works.

Comment: Short answer is: you can't

Comment: There is no practical way to change an asynchronously retrieved value into a synchronous retrieved value.  You will HAVE to write the code to use asynchronous programming techniques which, for a promise, means `await` or `.then()`.